# JavaFX setting combobox results in nullpointer

Tags: java, javafx

I have a small gui where I select an item in the first combobox which fills a second combobox with data and also changes the text of two labels.

Everything works as expected when I first select the first combobox (combobox_suppliers) and then the second combobox (combobox_radio) and it also updates the two labels (label_rad_substance, label_halftime). But if i then try to select a new option again from the first combobox I get alot of errors and nullpointer exceptions in the log. (The program still continues to function).

The errorlog is quite long but this line seams to be one of the problems:

```
label_rad_substance.setText(newValue.getSubstance().getName());
```

This is the code:

```
package gui;

import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import dao.RadiopharmaceuticalDao;
import dao.SupplierDao;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import model.Radiopharmaceutical;
import model.Room;
import model.Supplier;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private ObservableList<Supplier> supplierList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<Radiopharmaceutical> radioList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public DatePicker ankomstdatum = new DatePicker();
    public DatePicker kalibreringsdatum = new DatePicker();

    public ComboBox<Supplier> combobox_suppliers = new ComboBox<>();
    public ComboBox<Radiopharmaceutical> combobox_radio = new ComboBox<>();
    public ComboBox<Room> combobox_room = new ComboBox<>();

    public Label label_rad_substance = new Label();
    public Label label_halftime = new Label();

    public TextField text_kalibreringsaktivitet = new TextField();
    public TextField text_kalibreringstid = new TextField();
    public TextField text_batchnr = new TextField();
    public TextField text_kommentar = new TextField();
    public ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();

    public CheckBox check_kontamineringskontroll = new CheckBox();
    public Button button = new Button();



    public void addSuppliersToComboBox() {
        supplierList.addAll(new SupplierDao().getAll());
        combobox_suppliers.getItems().addAll(supplierList);
    }






    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        addSuppliersToComboBox();
        ankomstdatum.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        combobox_radio.setDisable(true);

        combobox_suppliers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->{
            combobox_radio.getItems().clear();
            combobox_radio.getItems().addAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new RadiopharmaceuticalDao().getRadiopharmaceuticalsBySupplierName(newValue.toString())));
            combobox_radio.setDisable(false);
            combobox_radio.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        });

        combobox_radio.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
            label_rad_substance.setText(newValue.getSubstance().getName());
            label_halftime.setText(newValue.getSubstance().getHalfLife()+"");
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: It's likely that `newValue` is null, or `newValue.getSubstance()` is null, have you tried printing those?

Comment: Will try, but all the labels get updated with the right information everytime. The console throws alot of errors but all functions still work as expected in the gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combobox_radio.getItems().clear();
```

Removes all items. Items that are not in the `items` list of a `ComboBox` are not eligible to be selected. For this reason the statement results in the selected item of `combo_radio` becoming `null` which results in a `NullPointerException` when trying to dereference `null` in `newValue.getSubstance()`.

You need to add a check for `null` to fix this, e.g.

```
combobox_radio.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)->{
    if (newValue == null) {
        label_rad_substance.setText("");
        label_halftime.setText("");
    } else {
        label_rad_substance.setText(newValue.getSubstance().getName());
        label_halftime.setText(newValue.getSubstance().getHalfLife()+"");
    }
});
```

---

BTW: I do not recommend initializing the injected fields. If those fields are properly injected, you created `Node`s that are never used. If they are not, you're better of immediately getting an exception that indicates injection does not work instead of having to find out why some change to a `Node` does not affect the GUI...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't really understand the part you commented on " initializing the injected fields". Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: @Burton: I'm refering to e.g. `public ComboBox<Radiopharmaceutical> combobox_radio = new ComboBox<>();`. Just check your code and you'll notice that you do not add the value in this field to a scene. What happens when loading the fxml is: The controller is created including all those objects that you create in the initializer (the places where you do `public Type fieldName = initialValue;`). Then `FXMLLoader` creates ***different*** objects based on the fxml and injects those objects to the fields based on the `fx:id`s overwriting the initial values.

Comment: Now there are 2 scenarios for each field: 1. There is a element with a corresponding `fx:id` and the initial values are simply dropped (the better case) or 2. you forgot to specify the `fx:id` in the fxml or you've got a typo in its value. Without intializing the fields you'll get a NullPointerException in some line that should provide much info about the source. If you initialize the fields though, you don't get a NPE and just wonder, why there's no effect on the displayed scene or why the values do not match those in the controls displayed...